# How do I us ngFor to iterate a minimum of 5 times

Tags: angular2-template

Ok, so this is probably a silly question, but after a few hours of trying to find the "right" way to accomplish this, I'm left to reach out for help.  I'm new to Angular2, so please be gentle.

I have a model that contains an array of parts, and that array will start out empty, but I need to present users with a collection of 5 rows of input fields so they can add the details for those 5 parts.  The limit is fixed at five, and they want the fields rendered by the component when they hit the page..

```
<tr *ngFor="let part of model.parts">
<td><input>...</td>
</tr>
```